# How to navigate back home using Monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, tabbar

I've got my MonoTouch app setup to use a TabBar and navigation controllers. I set HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true as soon as I get to view 1 or view 3.

E.g.

```
TabBar
   -Options 1 Navigation Controller
      -View1
      -View2
   -Options 2 Navigation Controller
      -View3
```

I can use the navigation controllers to move between views with a back button and everything is working as expected.

The problems comes when the current location is view1 or view3. How do I navigate back to the tabBar level? I can add a Back button manaully, but what logic should be under the button? I really need a TabController.PopToRootLevel(), but I can't find a similar method????

Edit: This code works, but I this doesn't look right. Its not animates and I presume this will cause memory leaks.

```
this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are looking for is PopToRootViewController and it is inside the UINavigationController class. So, inside the view controller from which you want to return to the start, call this (in your custom back button, or the button you will use):

```
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

Comment: But the NavigationController which the view has access to is not at the top level. Wouldn't that method just return the user to the start of the Navigation control, e.g. View1 or View3?

Comment: When a controller is pushed in a navigation controller, you have access to that navigation controller through its NavigationController property. If I get your question right, you have a tab controller which has two tabs. Each tab has a navigation controller in which you push various controllers, right?

Comment: Sorry. My description may be misleading. I have View0 which contains the TabBar. I can use NavigationControllers to move back to View1 without problem, but I can't seem to get any height then that, as there is no NavigationController on View0.

Comment: If there is no navigation controller on View0, then it is not a good practice. Make View0 the root view (or top level view) of the navigation controller.